# to see "accomplished" or to see "being accomplished"?

Tags: participles

> The goal, which they are unlikely to live to see ____, is to “cure, prevent or manage all diseases” in the next 80 years or so.

Which one is better for to fit the sentence, accomplished or being accomplished?

I think either one is correct, "accomplished” is like the shortened one of "being accomplished."

The answer given, however, is "accomplished," I don't understand why.

Comment: "Being accomplished," implies it is ongoing (continuous tense) at the same time it is "accomplished," i.e., completed.

Comment: Although both forms fit grammatically, the context makes it clear that they are unlikely to see the result  (accomplished) rather than the process.(being accomplished).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "being accomplished" is a process.

"The -ing ending is used to show the progressive aspect (progressive / continuous verb tenses)." [[1]](https://www.eslcafe.com/resources/grammar-lessons/verb-forms-and-verb-tenses/verb-forms-and-verb-tenses-5-the-ing-form)

2. "accomplished" (which is the past participle form) refers to completion. The final result.

Which makes more sense, that they will not live to see "an ongoing process", or they will not live to see "the final result"?

Since the process is already underway, they have already seen it (partly) being accomplished.